# Не могу подключиться по rdp к windows7 ultimate.

Tags: windows-7, rdp

Брандмауэр отключен,пинг есть,сеть доверенная (предприятие),пользователя создал,права пользователю дал.

К ХР подключение идет без проблем с того же компьютера. Экперимент проводил на обычном компьютере с win7 и на нетбуке с win7. Результат тот же.

Comment: Что означает "сеть доверенная (предприятие)"?

Comment: Когда я настраиваю сеть на win7 после ввода ip-адреса, маски подсети, dns-сервера  и сохранения настроек выходит запрос на выбор:- домашняя сеть, сеть предприятия, общественная сеть. От выбора зависит смогут ли другие пользователи пользоваться общими ресурсами данного компьютера. Это конечно можно сделать по-другому. Я просто ответил на вопрос.

Comment: ответ тот, что нужно, и говорит он о том, что всё-таки есть какой-то файервол. В нём нужно проверить разрешающее правило для сети или для порта RDP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Побольше бы инфы.Например, каким клиентом RDP пользуетесь.Для начала, проверьте, включена ли опция удаленного рабочего стола на win7. По умолчанию, она выключена.

Попробуй клиент Remmina.

Comment: Клиент тонкий. То есть подключаюсь с тонкого клиента TONK. На клиенте стоит какая-то непонятная система отдаленно напоминающая линукс. При подключении там можно еще протоколы выбирать. Может быть можно по другому протоколу подключиться? Или win7 поддерживает только rpd? Я имею в виду конечно для рабочего стола.

Comment: А может подключиться через UltraVNC? Там вроде можно подключиться через браузер поддерживающий java. На клиенте стоит mozilla firefox. Правда на клиенте нет JVM, насколько мне известно.

Answer (score 0):

свойствах системы требуется предварительно разрешить доступ к удаленному рабочему столу

Комп - Свойства - Дополнительные параметры системы - Удаленный доступ - и там проставь что надо)

Может поможет.

Comment: Эти вещи я уже делал - не помогло.